# Migration: AdMob to iAd on IOS clarification

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, admob, iad

I am new to iAd.

Currently trying to switch to iAd due to low revenue.

In Admob, we have this uniquely generated admob id from the website.
How does it work in iAd? Any unique string i need to integrate with iAd?

I have implemented the code for iAd. It is easy but i can't find the place
to edit the advertiser id.

Please clarify.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent on iAd part
It's just setup and run.

I assume behind the scenes it's using the application information to connect the uniqueness.

Is there a specific reason you need this? (Like per page differentiation, which is mainly what you lose)

Comment: I am still finding out how iAd works. If I don't need to input any hardcoded string then great but how it knows how to pay me then? I guess something is connected with the itunes connect?

Comment: Indeed you need to configure in iTunes connect the iAd App Network under contracts.